# qhull Library - C++ Interface

Tags: c++, convex-hull, qhull

The qhull library ( qhull.org) has several examples to start in his website, but all the information regarding to the C++ is not very useful to me.

I am trying to make a simple convex Hull of 3D points that I read from a file, I can´t use the technique that is suggested in the website of calling the qhull.exe as an external application because I need to make several convex hull from some modifications that I made in the data points.

I can´t find a simple example for doing this, can someone give me some help in this task? Any information would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: oh man, that library is so convoluted.  i just want to look up a bunch of functions it has for doing convex hull, and it's ... like in russian

Answer (score 21):

Since I had a hard time using Qhull with c++ myself and couldn't find any useful examples on the web, anddddd have finally succeeded in getting valid results, I'm posting my code here for future use.

> This answer works for windows, with visual studio 2012/3. I don't know how or if it works on other platforms

So, to start with things, after downloading qhull source files from [here](http://www.qhull.org/download/qhull-2012.1.zip)
and opening a project in VS, the only files you need to add are the following 2 directories:

```
libqhull/
libqhullcpp/
```

After adding these files to your project, add the following code (this is my way, obviously you can use your own way):

**Qhull.h**

```
namespace orgQhull{
//...
private:
    PointCoordinates *m_externalPoints;
//...
public:
    void runQhull3D(const std::vector<vec3> &points, const char* args);
    void runQhull(const PointCoordinates &points, const char *qhullCommand2);
//...
}
```

**Qhull.cpp**

```
void Qhull::runQhull3D(const std::vector<vec3> &points, const char* args)
{
    m_externalPoints = new PointCoordinates(3);  //3 = dimension
    vector<double> allPoints;
    for each (vec3 p in points)
    {
        allPoints.push_back(p.x());
        allPoints.push_back(p.y());
        allPoints.push_back(p.z());
    }

    m_externalPoints->append(allPoints); //convert to vector<double>
    runQhull(*m_externalPoints, args);
}

void Qhull::runQhull(const PointCoordinates &points, const char *qhullCommand2)
{
    runQhull(points.comment().c_str(), points.dimension(), points.count(), &*points.coordinates(), qhullCommand2);
}
```

Finally this is how to use the code:

```
//not sure all these includes are needed
#include "RboxPoints.h"
#include "QhullError.h"
#include "Qhull.h"
#include "QhullQh.h"
#include "QhullFacet.h"
#include "QhullFacetList.h"
#include "QhullLinkedList.h"
#include "QhullVertex.h"
#include "QhullSet.h"
#include "QhullVertexSet.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    orgQhull::Qhull qhull;
    std::vector<vec3> vertices;
    qhull.runQhull3D(vertices, "Qt");

    QhullFacetList facets = qhull.facetList();
    for (QhullFacetList::iterator it = facets.begin(); it != facets.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!(*it).isGood()) continue;
        QhullFacet f = *it;
        QhullVertexSet vSet = f.vertices();
        for (QhullVertexSet::iterator vIt = vSet.begin(); vIt != vSet.end(); ++vIt)
        {
            QhullVertex v = *vIt;
            QhullPoint p = v.point();
            double * coords = p.coordinates();
            vec3 aPoint = vec3(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]);
            // ...Do what ever you want
        }
    }
    
    // Another way to iterate (c++11), and the way the get the normals
    std::vector<std::pair<vec3, double> > facetsNormals;
    for each (QhullFacet facet : qhull.facetList().toStdVector())
    {
        if (facet.hyperplane().isDefined())
        {
            auto coord = facet.hyperplane().coordinates();
            vec3 normal(coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]);
            double offset = facet.hyperplane().offset();
            facetsNormals.push_back(std::pair<vec3, double>(normal, offset));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I copied this code from my project and have modified it a bit to be more informative but haven't compiled this example.

Comment: @Raaj thanks for pointing it out for others. Feel free to edit my answer with a thread safe code and I'll review and accept it

Comment: There isn't. I've looked through the whole internet/github/codeproject everything. There is no C/C++ example of a Convex/Concave hull algorithm.

Comment: If im not wrong..qhull has come up with this new re-entrant qhull that is thread safe. I've not found any examples of using that code

Comment: qhull 2015 is re-entrant but not thread safe: see http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-code.htm#reentrant and http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-code.htm#cpp

Comment: Thank you, this post really was useful.

Comment: Great answer! Do you know why it can happen that the normal (in 3 dimensions) is `(nan, nan, nan)`? I guess this is what the function `facet.hyperplane.isDefined()` refers to?

Comment: What has to be done if the points are not in 3d? What if I have points in, say, 8 dimension with 8 coordinates? Can one just change `vec3` to `vec8`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple example using re-entrant qhull from c++. I think it might be useful.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "Qhull.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::vector<double> points_3D = {0, 0, 0,
                                     0, 1, 0,
                                     1, 1, 0,
                                     1, 0, 0,
                                     0, 0, 1,
                                     0, 1, 1,
                                     1, 1, 1,
                                     1, 0, 1};

    int ndim = 3;
    int num_points = points_3D.size() / ndim;

    std::string comment = ""; // rbox commands, see http://www.qhull.org/html/rbox.htm
    std::string qhull_command = ""; // For qhull commands, see http://www.qhull.org/html/qhull.htm

    try
    {
        orgQhull::Qhull qhull = orgQhull::Qhull(comment.c_str(), ndim, num_points, points_3D.data(), qhull_command.c_str());
        std::cout << "qhull.hullDimension(): " << qhull.hullDimension() << "\n";
        std::cout << "qhull.volume(): " << qhull.volume() << "\n";
        std::cout << "qhull.area(): " << qhull.area() << "\n";
    }
    catch (orgQhull::QhullError &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return e.errorCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This post had the only examples I could find of qHull so I wanted to add this snippet of code for how to get the convex hull of a 2D set of points using qhull.

```
#include <vector>

#include "my_point.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/Qhull.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullVertex.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullVertexSet.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullPoint.h"

std::vector<my_point> getConvexHull2D(const std::vector<my_point> &scatteredPoints)
{
  std::vector<my_point> cHull;
  if(scatteredPoints.size() < 3) return cHull;

  std::vector<double> inputVertices;
  for(int i = 0; i < (int)scatteredPoints.size(); i++)
  {
    const my_point &pt = scatteredPoints[i];
    inputVertices.push_back(pt.x);
    inputVertices.push_back(pt.y);
  }

  orgQhull::Qhull qhull;

  int ndim = 2;
  int num_points = inputVertices.size() / ndim;
  const char *inputComments = "";
  const char *qHullCommands = "";

  qhull.runQhull(inputComments, ndim, num_points, inputVertices.data(), qHullCommands);

  for(const orgQhull::QhullVertex &v: qhull.vertexList())
  {
    const orgQhull::QhullPoint &qhullPt = v.point();
    auto coords = qhullPt.coordinates(); // list of doubles
    cHull.push_back(my_point(coords[0], coords[1]));
  }

  // the vertices are not sorted?
  CCWSort(cHull.data(), cHull.size());
  return cHull;
}
```

I also had to build the libraries and link `qhullcpp.lib` and `qhullstatic_r.lib` in addition to adding `qhull/src` to the include path. There is a Qt project included that you can open and build which will build the libs for you.

I tried to use boost first but it was conflicting too much with some legacy code. This might not be the most efficient implementation, but it's much better than what I had previously.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me on my ubuntu machine -

1. As mentioned on github readme,

   - download and extract Qhull (either GitHub, .tgz file, or .zip file)
   - make
   - make install
   - make test
2. The sample code `qhull_vol.cpp` gets delaunay triangulation for the points randomly spread on a sphere of radius 1. It also checks if geometry is convex or not. (sources on internet are used for a few parts in following example)

```
#include "libqhullcpp/RboxPoints.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullError.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/Qhull.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullQh.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullFacet.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullFacetList.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullLinkedList.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullVertex.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullSet.h"
#include "libqhullcpp/QhullVertexSet.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <libqhull/qhull_a.h>

using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using orgQhull::Qhull;
using orgQhull::QhullError;
using orgQhull::QhullFacet;
using orgQhull::QhullFacetList;
using orgQhull::QhullFacetListIterator;
using orgQhull::QhullFacetSet;
using orgQhull::QhullPoint;
using orgQhull::QhullPoints;
using orgQhull::QhullPointsIterator;
using orgQhull::QhullQh;
using orgQhull::QhullVertex;
using orgQhull::QhullVertexList;
using orgQhull::QhullVertexListIterator;
using orgQhull::QhullVertexSet;
using orgQhull::QhullVertexSetIterator;
using orgQhull::RboxPoints;


double tetrahedronVolume(const orgQhull::QhullPoint &a, const orgQhull::QhullPoint &b,
                         const orgQhull::QhullPoint &c, const orgQhull::QhullPoint &d) 
{
    // Compute vectors
    std::vector<double> ad = {d[0]-a[0], d[1]-a[1], d[2]-a[2]};
    std::vector<double> ab = {b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1], b[2]-a[2]};
    std::vector<double> ac = {c[0]-a[0], c[1]-a[1], c[2]-a[2]};
    
    // Compute the cross product of ab and ac
    std::vector<double> cross_ab_ac = {
        ab[1]*ac[2] - ab[2]*ac[1],
        ab[2]*ac[0] - ab[0]*ac[2],
        ab[0]*ac[1] - ab[1]*ac[0]
    };
    
    // Compute the dot product of ad and the cross product
    double dot = ad[0]*cross_ab_ac[0] + ad[1]*cross_ab_ac[1] + ad[2]*cross_ab_ac[2];
    
    return std::abs(dot) / 6.0;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vertices;
    int ndim = 3;

    orgQhull::Qhull qhull;
    const int N = 500;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_theta(0.0, 2 * M_PI);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_phi(0.0, M_PI);

    // generate random points on spherical surface r=1
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        double theta = dist_theta(gen);
        double phi = dist_phi(gen);
        double x = sin(phi) * cos(theta);
        double y = sin(phi) * sin(theta);
        double z = cos(phi);
        vertices.push_back(x);
        vertices.push_back(y);
        vertices.push_back(z);

    }
    // if following centre point is included then geometry would not be convex
    /*vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(0);
    */

    qhull.runQhull("", ndim, vertices.size()/ndim, vertices.data(), "d QJ");  
    // "d" for Delaunay triangulation
    // QJ for jiggle of for cospherical points
    
    
    double totalVolume = 0;
    orgQhull::QhullFacetList facets = qhull.facetList();
    for(orgQhull::QhullFacetList::iterator it = facets.begin(); it != facets.end(); ++it) {
        if(!(*it).isUpperDelaunay()) {
            orgQhull::QhullVertexSet vertices = (*it).vertices();
            if(vertices.size() != 4) continue;  // Only process tetrahedra
            auto vertIter = vertices.begin();
            orgQhull::QhullPoint a = (*vertIter++).point();
            orgQhull::QhullPoint b = (*vertIter++).point();
            orgQhull::QhullPoint c = (*vertIter++).point();
            orgQhull::QhullPoint d = (*vertIter).point();
            totalVolume += tetrahedronVolume(a, b, c, d);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Volume from delaunay triangulation : " << totalVolume << "\n";
    std::cout << "Volume of sphere r=1 : " << 4./3.*M_PI*(1.0*1.0*1.0) << "\n";

    // check if all points are on convex geometry
    orgQhull::Qhull qhullc;
    qhullc.runQhull("", ndim, vertices.size()/ndim, vertices.data(), "Qt");
    orgQhull::QhullVertexList es = qhullc.vertexList();
    if(es.size() == vertices.size()/ndim) {
        std::cout << "The geometry is convex." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "The geometry is not convex." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

3. Makefile to compile the code (make sure that `QHULL_INCLUDE` and `QHULL_LIB` paths have appropriate files for qhull after installation in 1st step otherwise change paths. Use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if needed from qhull folder)

```
# Compiler to use
CXX = g++

# Qhull include and library paths, adjust if necessary
QHULL_INCLUDE = /usr/local/include/
QHULL_LIB = /usr/local/lib/

# Compiler and linker flags
CXXFLAGS = -I$(QHULL_INCLUDE) -Wall -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS = -L$(QHULL_LIB) -lqhullcpp -lqhull_r

# Target executable name
TARGET = qhull_vol

# Source file name
SOURCE = qhull_vol.cpp

# Rule to build the target
$(TARGET): $(SOURCE)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

# Rule to clean intermediate files and target
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)

# Default rule to be executed when calling 'make' without arguments
all: $(TARGET)
```

4. Execute the code as `./qhull_vol` from the terminal